# Magnification after refraction

Tags: optics

[image]The distance between two light rays changes as they pass from one material to another. I want to know the magnification defined as d2/d1 in terms of the angles theta1 and theta2. So far I am not able to relate d of both rays to refracted angles. Can someone guide please!

Comment: Hint: can you relate $d_1$ and $d_2$ to the distance between the incidence points of the two rays?

Comment: I thought about it and exactly d1 will be the distance between the incidence point of the two parallel incoming rays and then d2 is the distance between their refracted part. But could not think of a way to have a relation which will give these distances between the two incident rays as well as the distance between the two refracted rays.

Comment: What I mean is, you could try to relate $d_1$ and $d_2$ to the distance between the *points* where the rays are incident, i.e. the intersection points of the dashed lines with the interface.